# start-yarn.sh is throwing error in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, rhel6

Trying to start yarn deamons with `start-yarn.sh` while doing getting below error

```
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-blr-nano-52.out
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

I have mentioned the path in the .bashrc but still unable to fix the issue.

Any help will be great to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you share the log in /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-blr-nano-52.log

Comment: logs in yarn-root-resourcemanager-blr-nano-‌​52.log:
ulimit -a
core file size:(blocks, -c) 0
data seg size:(kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority:(-e) 0
file size:(blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals:(-i) 127661
max locked memory:(kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size:(kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files:(-n) 65535
pipe size:(512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues:(bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority:(-r) 0
stack size:(kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time:(seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes:(-u) unlimited
virtual memory:(kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks:(-x) unlimited

Comment: are you tailing last 10 lines? check the full /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-blr-nano-‌​52.log for any error

Comment: This issue was happening because of the $HADOOP_HOME for hadoop installation. In 2.7, this has been changed into $HADOOP_PREFIX and aditionally I had also made changes in ~/.bash_profile. Because of which I was facing the issue.


Thank you guys.